# How to verify a signature with a public key provided in .pem File?

Tags: c#, certificate

How can I verify a signature with a public key provided in .pem File?

I use the flowing code:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider CrRsa;

var reader21 = File.OpenText(@"C:GTLpublicKey.pem");
var x = new PemReader(reader21);
var y = (RsaKeyParameters)x.ReadObject();

CrRsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)RSACryptoServiceProvider.Create();
RSAParameters pa = new RSAParameters();
pa.Modulus = y.Modulus.ToByteArray();
pa.Exponent = y.Exponent.ToByteArray();
CrRsa.ImportParameters(pa);
```

`y` returns `null`, results in an Error at `pa.Modulus = y.Modulus.ToByteArray();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAVerifier = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

//Read public Key From Text File.

StreamReader PubKeyReader = File.OpenText(txtPublicKeyFile.Text);

string publicKey = PubKeyReader.ReadToEnd();

//Adding public key to RSACryptoServiceProvider object.

RSAVerifier.FromXmlString(publicKey);

//Reading the Signature to verify.

FileStream Signature = new FileStream(txtVerifySign.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

BinaryReader SignatureReader = new BinaryReader(Signature);

byte[] SignatureData = SignatureReader.ReadBytes((int)Signature.Length);

//Reading the Signed File for Verification.

FileStream Verifyfile = new FileStream(txtVerifyFile.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

BinaryReader VerifyFileReader = new BinaryReader(Verifyfile);

byte[] VerifyFileData = VerifyFileReader.ReadBytes((int)Verifyfile.Length);

//Comparing.

bool isValidsignature = RSAVerifier.VerifyData(VerifyFileData, "SHA1", SignatureData);

if (isValidsignature)

{

      Signature.Close();

      Verifyfile.Close();

}

else

{


    Signature.Close();

    Verifyfile.Close();

}
```

Comment: Public key of the certificate used for signing is saved and later used for verification.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the proposed answer.

RSACryptoServiceProvider can't read a PEM file through "FromXMLString".

However, it gave me the idea to export the PEM file to XML.

I found this site [that makes the online conversion](http://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter)

Then it worked perfectly!

Comment: Im not sure it answers the question, but Its a nice resource

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but probably is the problem that you forgot a backsslash:

```
var reader21 = File.OpenText(@"C:\GTLpublicKey.pem");
//                               ^
```

Comment: var reader21 = File.OpenText(@"C:GTLpublicKey.pem"); is working fine

Comment: var y = (RsaKeyParameters)x.ReadObject();
i dont know why this part returns a null value.

Comment: I think the problem is that the file does not exist, caused by a missing backslash. A normal filename cannot contain a `:` sign. AFIK that is reserved for drive names.

Comment: yes you are right.But,while i use the code @"C:GTLpublicKey.pem",it works differently.it reads the file GTLpublicKey.pem from the Desktop.